# React Native: I cannot upload the bundled package of react native app on google play console through Github Actions

Tags: react-native, github-actions

I am trying to make a CI/CD pipeline for my react native application through github actions. When i am trying to upload my bundle on google play console, i am getting the following error:

Run r0adkll/upload-google-play@v1
Warning: WARNING!! 'releaseFile' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please migrate to 'releaseFiles'
Error: Unable to find any release file matching

Following is my build.gradle configuration:

```
Build.gradle:

signingConfigs {
     // release {
    //     storeFile file('AIM_TAB.keystore')
   //      storePassword 'AIM_TAB_2023'
  //       keyAlias 'AIM_TAB'
  //       keyPassword 'AIM_TAB_2023'}

buildTypes {
    debug {signingConfig signingConfigs.debug}
    release {
      // signingConfig signingConfigs.release
         minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
```

Following is my react-native.yml code for CI/CD pipeline through github actions:

name: React Native App Deployment on PlayConsole

on:
push:
branches: ['production']
pull_request:
branches: ['production']

jobs:
build:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- name: Checkout code
uses: actions/checkout@v2

```
  - name: Set up Node.js
    uses: actions/setup-node@v2
    with:
      node-version: 18
      check-latest: true

  - name: Install dependencies
    run: |
      npm install --force || true
    
  - name: Build Android Bundle
    run: |
      cd /home/runner/work/NAYEL-APP/NAYEL-APP/android
      ./gradlew bundleRelease
  
  - name: Sign App Bundle
    uses: r0adkll/sign-android-release@v1
    with:
      releaseDirectory: android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release
      signingKeyBase64: ${{ secrets.KEYSTORE_FILE }}
      alias: ${{ secrets.KEY_ALIAS }}
      keyStorePassword: ${{ secrets.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD }}
      keyPassword: ${{ secrets.KEY_PASSWORD }}

  - name: Deploy to Play Store 
    uses: r0adkll/upload-google-play@v1
    with:
      serviceAccountJsonPlainText: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_PLAY_JSON }}
      packageName: com.aimmotors.nayel
      releaseFile: /home/runner/work/NAYEL-APP/NAYEL-APP/android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab
      track: internal
```

Comment: Verify if `/home/runner/work/NAYEL-APP/NAYEL-APP/android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab` exists.